# maintenance mode removed automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, maintenance

I have put my site under maintenance mode. But the site is becoming live and the `maintenance.flag` file is getting deleted automatically. I didn't change anything and I have no idea how this is happening.

Someone kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: please specify Magento version

Comment: magento 1.9.0.1